# Defaults in python dictConfig

Tags: python, logging, yaml, config, default

If I define my logging config in an .ini file, I can pass default arguments to the config like this:

In the .ini file:

```
[handler_fileHandler]
class = logging.FileHandler
level = ERROR
formatter = simpleFormatter
# use args to pass arguemnts to the handler 
args = (f'{logfilename}', 'a') # filename, append
```

Loading the config from the file:

```
# load config and pass default arguemnts
config.fileConfig(
    fname="./logging.ini",
    # pass the argument filename for the filehandler
    defaults={ 'logfilename' : getSomeName() } 
    disable_existing_loggers=False, 
)
```

Is there any possibility to do the same when I use a yaml file? According to the docs I would say no.

Comment: You would load a YAML config via `dictConfig()` so you first load a dict which you can modify at will before handing it over to `dictConfig()`, therefore definitely possible. Is it a requirement to `eval` stuff from the YAML file, or would it be okay if you just pushed the externally provided values into the loaded dict after loading it from YAML?

Answer (score 0):

you can set it like this:

```
args=('%(logfilename)s',)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.